# Which kind of datatype use in dataTablesParameters insted of any

Tags: typescript

```
ajax: (dataTablesParameters:**any**, callback): void => {
        dataTablesParameters.minNumber = dataTablesParameters.start + 1;
        dataTablesParameters.maxNumber =dataTablesParameters.start + dataTablesParameters.length;
        const orderFeiled = dataTablesParameters.order[0].column;
        const sortingOrder = dataTablesParameters.order[0].dir == 'asc' ? true :false;
```

Answer (score 0):

From usage, it looks like this typing would fit:

```
const ajax = (
    dataTablesParameters: {
        start: number;
        length: number;
        order: {
            column: string;
            dir: 'asc' | 'desc'
        }[];
        minNumber?: number;
        maxNumber?: number;
    },
    callback: () => void
) => {
    dataTablesParameters.minNumber = dataTablesParameters.start + 1;
    dataTablesParameters.maxNumber = dataTablesParameters.start + dataTablesParameters.length;
    const orderFailed = dataTablesParameters.order[0].column;
    const sortingOrder = dataTablesParameters.order[0].dir == 'asc' ? true : false;
}
```

However, I would advise against mutating `dataTablesParameters` by adding new properties, because that might eventually cause the code to be more complicated than it has to be.
Have a great day!

Comment: whenever i assign these data type it gives the error on ajax like these(Type '(dataTablesParameters: IDataTable, callback: (data: any) => void) => void' is not assignable to type 'string | AjaxSettings | FunctionAjax | undefined'.
  
    Types of parameters 'dataTablesParameters' and 'data' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IDataTable': start, length, orderts(2322)
index.d.ts(1315, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ajax' which is declared here on type 'Settings'
)